# wget failure(404) for downloading the whole page including images from blog platform

Tags: linux, wget

I tried

```
wget --page-requisites --html-extension --restrict-file-names=windows
"URL:)"
```

for downloading the whole page including css and images of a blog article on Medium,

but when I actually opened the html file, it threw a 404 page error after loading the page I specified.

So I tried to stop the transition to a 404 page from popping up
while the web browser was loading the page,

but even when the target page was shown by pressing an esc key,
I saw the images are still blank with the outcome files
generated by the command above.

Is there something I missed with that command?